# Prove the following statement about a function that is continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity

I was given this problem the following problem in my exam:

> A function continuous on $[a,b]$ attains a minimum value on $[a,b]$.
>
> > **Note:** proof should not involve ***compact sets*** or ***sequences***.

Help me with this proof please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the completeness axiom in Real numbers:
For any closed interval in $\mathbb R $ ,there exists a greatest lower
bound,
called the infimum,which is equal to the minimum of that set.

Since the function is continuous and the domain is a closed interval,
it follows that its range is also a closed interval,So the completeness axiom holds for the Range of that function,
i.e. We get a minimum.

See also : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

ADD:To see why the range would be a closed set,
Consider $c$ to be a point in the interval $[a,b]$,
and assume it is one of the end points of the function's range. Then if the range was not a closed interval,Then $f(c)$ would not be in the range,and thus :$$ \lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c) $$ would not hold,
Since the function would not be defined on the point $c$, 
and we would get a contradiction that the function is continuous
 on the interval $[a,b]$,Therefore it is a closed set.

Comment: That is a proof?

Comment: @socrates leave behind the socratic method.. ;P

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?. It completely follows from the completeness axiom and the defintion of continuity. Although if the function was also  said to be differetiable ,you could use the fact the it had to be monotone in a sub interval $[m,n]and then show that a monotone (strictly increasing or decreasing function) attains its extremum at it's end points,m,n and to say that the minumum exists... but that is an overkill and it does follow from the completeness axiom.

Comment: How do you prove that the range is closed without using sequences or passing through compactness?

Comment: By using the condition that the function is continuous.see:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: Regarding your addendum: I don't understand what you mean when you say that $c$ is one of the endpoints of the function range. In fact $c$ is in the domain, and we don't know that there is a point which attains the infimum (that's what we have to prove). For instance what would $c$ be in the case $f(x)=x$ in $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)=\frac{a+b}{2}$?